# Passing List as argument in spark scala function gives error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one spark scala udf which takes one parameter as column of dataframe and other parameter as List but when I run the function it throws error pointing to list argument as

`type mismatch, found spark.sql.row ,required spark.sql.column`

I am running udf with argument as follows,

udf_name($"column_name",List_name)

Please Guide

Answer (score 0):

You need to define multiple instances of your UDF with the lists you want to pass.
Since the lists are local scala variables you can do that just before the call (spark will ship the udf to the various executors)
e.g.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df=List("A","B").toDF
def to_be_udf(s: String, l : List[String])=if (l.isEmpty) "" else "has values"
val udf1=udf((s:String) => to_be_udf (s,List("a")))
val udf2=udf((s:String) => to_be_udf (s,List()))
df.select(udf1($"value"),udf2($"value")).show()

+----------+----------+
|UDF(value)|UDF(value)|
+----------+----------+
|has values|          |
|has values|          |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: HI Arnon  I made changes as suggested by you but got error my code is,                                                                
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit                                                                          
    df_col.withColumn("newcol",udf_getMaxMatch($"col",lit(L))                                           
    I got error as => java.lang.RuntimeException:unsupported literal type class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon List([12],[1234]) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77).........

Comment: what's the definition of your udf

Comment: val udf_getMaxMatchC = udf{(inpStr:String,codeList:List[String])=>{def getMaxIter(inpStr:String,codeList:List[String],maxMatch:String):String={if(codeList.isEmpty){maxMatch}else{val cmp = codeList.head if(cmp == inpStr.substring(0,cmp.length)){if(cmp.length > maxMatch.length){getMaxIter(inpStr,codeList.tail,cmp)}else{getMaxIter(inpStr,codeList.tail,maxMatch)}}else{getMaxIter(inpStr,codeList.tail,maxMatch)}}}if(codeList.isEmpty){""}else{getMaxIter(inpStr,codeList,"")}}}

Comment: sorry my bad - fixed the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the constant value to an udf using `lit`, or alternatively define a method with returns an UDF (my preferred way):

```
def udf_name(List_name:List[String]) = {
  udf((name:String) => {
    // do something 
    List_name.contains(name)
  })
}

val List_name : List[String] = ???

df
  .withColumn("is_name_in_list", udf_name(List_name)($"column_name"))
```

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit